# Top view and Bottom view heights are fixed, middle view need to fit in remaining space

Tags: react-native, view, flexbox, react-native-stylesheet

I have 3 views `top view`, `middle view`, `bottom view`. The `top view` and `bottom view` has it's components and they are fixed in height in a vertically aligned `container view`. Now, I need the `middle view` to be flexible in height, i.e., the height of `middle view` can be vary based on screen height, it needs to be fit in remaining space. Can you please help me to figure out this.

Comment: set height of middle view equal to ```Dimension.get('screen').height - topViewHeight - bottomviewHeight```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>

  <View> ... </View> <!-- Top View ->

  <View style={{flex:1}}> ... </View> <!-- Middle View ->

  <View> ... </View> <!-- Bottom View ->

</View>
```